# SQL JOIN returns multiple items onto 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, multiple-columns

I have 2 SQL tables.

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('A', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE A;
    END
GO
CREATE TABLE A
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](80) DEFAULT('Guest'),
    [Acct_Num] [NVARCHAR](255)
)
GO

IF OBJECT_ID ('B', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
        DROP TABLE B;
    END
GO
CREATE TABLE B
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) Primary Key NOT NULL,
    [Name] [NVARCHAR](80) DEFAULT('Unk'),
    [Acct_Num] [NVARCHAR](255)
)
GO
```

Adding in test data

```
INSERT INTO [A] ([Name], [Acct_Num]) VALUES ('Test1', '5006347')
INSERT INTO [A] ([Name], [Acct_Num]) VALUES ('Test2', '5006348')
INSERT INTO [A] ([Name], [Acct_Num]) VALUES ('Test3', '5006349')
GO

INSERT INTO [B] ([Name], [Acct_Num]) VALUES ('Attach1', '5006347')
INSERT INTO [B] ([Name], [Acct_Num]) VALUES ('Attach2', '5006347')
GO
```

What I am looking for is a query to return the A[Name], A[Acct_Num], and B[Name] where an A[Acct_Num] matches B[Acct_Num]. B[Name] must be added to the result as an attached column. *(Sample output given below)*

Now my immediate need is for only possibly 2 items in table B, but what if it was 5?

I tried something like this but it doesn't return values in the AS 'column name'.

```
DECLARE @Row_Cnt Integer = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [B] WHERE B.Acct_Num = '5006347')
SELECT A.[Name], A.[Acct_Num],
CASE WHEN @Row_Cnt = '1' THEN
    (SELECT MIN(B.[Name]) FROM B WHERE B.Acct_Num = A.Acct_Num)
    END  AS 'Attach 1', 
CASE WHEN @Row_Cnt = '2' THEN
    (SELECT MAX(B.[Name]) FROM B WHERE B.Acct_Num = A.Acct_Num)
    END AS 'Attach 2'
FROM A WHERE A.Acct_Num = '5006347'
```

Now this works using MIN & MAX but this would fail to get all matches if there was more than 2 items found.

```
SELECT A.[Name], A.[Acct_Num], MIN(B.[Name]) AS 'Attach 1', MAX(B.[Name]) AS 'Attach 2'
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.Acct_Num = A.Acct_Num
WHERE A.Acct_Num = '5006347'
GROUP BY A.Name, A.Acct_Num
```

RESULT:

```
Name  | Acct_Num | Attach 1 | Attach 2
Test1 | 5006347  | Attach1  | Attach2
```

And this is not a very glamorous (although functional) solution for my 2 column quest but I sense a need for more returned columns is coming.

So what is a more efficient method that would accommodate an unknown amount of items returned.

Thank you!

Comment: A SQL query returns a fixes set of columns.  In order to have a variable number, you need dynamic SQL.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I would very much like to see an example.

Comment: Additional Expansion of the question: What if I need two columns from Table B, assuming there was another column [Size] which doesn't necessarily match the same size as the others.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL is as if you concatenate SQL code in a "programming" language, but still you can use just SQL, e.g. like this:

```
DECLARE @NameA NVARCHAR(80), @NameB NVARCHAR(80), @Acct_Num NVARCHAR(255),
   @DynamicSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @i INT

SET @Acct_Num = '5006347'
SET @i = 1

SELECT @NameA  = [Name] FROM [A] WHERE Acct_Num = @Acct_Num

-- Start of Dynamic SQL (or dynamic SELECT) - I include columns
-- A.[Name] and Acct_Num, which I've know already
SELECT @DynamicSQL = N'SELECT N''' + @NameA + N''' AS NameA, N''' + 
   @Acct_Num + ''' AS Acct_Num,'

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD LOCAL FOR
   SELECT B.[Name]
   FROM B
   JOIN A ON A.Acct_Num = B.Acct_Num
   WHERE A.[Name] = @NameA

OPEN cur

WHILE(1=1)
BEGIN
   FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @NameB

   IF @@FETCH_STATUS <> 0
      BREAK;

   -- Add each row from cursor to the dynamic sql string as a column. 
   -- Added columns are named 'Col' and order number (eg. Col1, Col2 etc.)
   SELECT @DynamicSQL = @DynamicSQL + N'N''' + @NameB + N''' AS Col' +
      CAST(@i AS NVARCHAR) + ','
   SELECT @i = @i+1
END

SELECT @DynamicSQL = LEFT(@DynamicSQL, LEN(@DynamicSQL) - 1)  -- remove last comma

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicSQL
```

It is not optimised code but I hope for a demonstration it is ok. If you have multiple names in A table for one Acct_Num, the code need some modification indeed.

Comment: I like both answers.  P Lion's slips easily into my existing and lengthy query although I will need to do a little string extraction on the data this doesn't end the world. I like Zahiro's answer and had I just been starting on this would probably opt for not post query manipulations. Both answers do what I asked so both are correct. I will test on these then post the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Dynamic SQL it is possible, in case you are working with version 2017, to obtain a dynamically composed output for one column which is built as a list of all the values thanks to a new aggregation function.
Then it is up to your code to split the data in a way it could be seen as multiple columns.

```
SELECT A.[Name], A.[Acct_Num], STRING_AGG(B.[Name], ',') AS Attaches
FROM A
JOIN B ON B.Acct_Num = A.Acct_Num
WHERE A.Acct_Num = '5006347'
GROUP BY A.Name, A.Acct_Num
```

Name    Acct_Num    Attaches
Test1   5006347 Attach1,Attach2

In case you would like to see more examples of this you can google for group_concat which is the MySQL equivalent function which has been around since a long while before.